# An entity/database design dilemma

Tags: database-design, relational-database

This is a question more related to design than actual programming. Suppose I have a User profile in a system and this profile involves basic and advanced information. Suppose it also will involve a basic search and an advanced search over this data. In situations like this ones, is it better to use one big entity without difference between basic and advanced data or split this informations in two entities, where the advanced one inherits from basic one? Consider again that searches will be performed over all this data. Also consider that the "advanced entity" may involve Enum or Set like fields. Would it be ok to use SET and ENUM fields in these case or should I further split my advanced entity/table in further one-to-one relationships?

Here an example:

```
Profile (base entity)
+- Location (will probably poit to a location table)
 - Birthdate
 - Sex
 - Avatar
 - Pictures (will point to pictures entity)

Advanced profile (extends Profile)
+- eye_color (enum like)
 - hair_color (enum like)
 - weight
 - heigth
 - favorite_hobbies (set like)
 - favorite_quote
 - known_programming_languages (set like)
```

And so on! The example is very basic, but actual project would involve much more data.

Would you have any suggestion about the best way to design this stuff?

Comment: II would advise against using set datatype..

Comment: The answer depends on the actual usage of these tables, so hard to give you a definite answer!

Comment: A reasonable decision can be made only of one has an idea of quantitative data: how many users there will be, how long is a typical user tuple with basic and advanced properties, how fast the queries should be, how much this table will grow and in what time, etc. And I too advise against using set datatypes.

Comment: One reason for splitting a profile table into more than one table is when the columns in the second table are optional and would be null most of the time if the profile was one table.

Answer (score 0):

For all data tied to the profile itself in a one-to-one manner it should be stored in one table where the key is the profile's ID. Let's call this the profile_header table. In your example the profile_header table would contain: **profile id**, location, birthdate, sex, avatar, eye_color, hair_color, weight, height, favorite_quote.

You can extend this model with other tables that may have multiple entries that tie to the profile header table (one-to-many). In your example I would create these tables.

- profile_pictures (key on profile id and picture id)
- profile_hobbies (key on profile id and hobby id)
- profile_programming_labguages (key on profile id and programming language id)

In this setup you could have lots of pictures, hobbies and programming languages tied to a single profile.